# Computed bounds in guvectorize specifications

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a vectorizable function which I'm writing using NumBa which has a non-standard signature: it maps a vector of length `n` into an array of dimensions `(n + 1, n)`. As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this directly in NumBa: function signatures can't have arithmetic in them, so the simple signature `(n) -> (n+1, n)` is not possible. I've found an inelegant but workable work-around: I wrap this function in another one which includes a dummy argument of length `m` and then uses the signature `(n), (m) -> (m, n)`.

My question is this: is there a less brittle way to do this?

Comment: The numpy [spec](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/c-api.generalized-ufuncs.html) makes reference to a derived dimension, but numba doesn't seem to support this, and numpy says the caller would have to allocate the output anyways, which is basically what you are doing.